# Recommended gem versions and configurations for site5? I'm getting memory errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

As far as I can tell, I've got my gems set up appropriately to run on Ruby 1.8.7 p370.  I've followed the site's instructions to get the site running on phusion passenger. That's the required version on site5.  I've tried downgrading rails but activerecord-mysql-adaptor needs rails 3.2+ so I'm reluctant to drop past that. I'm not sure this is the problem so I'm hoping someone has encountered it.  Thanks.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot allocate memory -- /home/visualha/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/integration.rb
```

Here's my gemlist:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.2.12, 3.2.11, 3.2.9, 3.2.2, 3.0.3, 2.3.8)
actionpack (3.2.13, 3.2.12, 3.2.11, 3.2.9, 3.2.2, 3.0.3, 2.3.8)
activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.12, 3.2.11, 3.2.9, 3.2.2, 3.0.3)
activerecord (3.2.12, 3.2.11, 3.2.9, 3.2.2, 3.0.3, 2.3.8)
activerecord-mysql-adapter (0.0.1)
activeresource (3.2.12, 3.2.11, 3.2.9, 3.2.2, 3.0.3, 2.3.8)
activesupport (3.2.13, 3.2.12, 3.2.11, 3.2.9, 3.2.2, 3.0.3, 2.3.8)
acts-as-taggable-on (2.3.3)
adauth (1.2.1)
arel (3.0.2, 2.0.6)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0)
bootstrap-sass (2.3.1.0, 2.3.0.1)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.7)
capistrano (2.11.2, 2.5.19)
capybara (2.0.2)
carrierwave (0.8.0)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
childprocess (0.3.8)
chronic (0.6.7, 0.6.6)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.2, 1.4.0)
commonjs (0.2.6)
cucumber (1.2.1)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
daemon_controller (1.0.0, 0.2.6)
daemons (1.1.8, 1.1.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.3, 1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
execjs (1.4.0)
faraday (0.8.4)
faraday_middleware (0.8.8)
fastthread (1.0.7)
fcgi (0.8.8)
ferret (0.11.8.4, 0.11.6)
ffi (1.4.0)
flvtool2 (1.0.6)
formtastic (2.2.1)
formtastic-bootstrap (2.0.0)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
gherkin (2.11.6)
highline (1.6.11, 1.6.1)
hike (1.2.2, 1.2.1)
hoe (3.5.3, 3.5.0)
hoe-bundler (1.2.0)
hoe-debugging (1.1.1)
hoe-gemspec (1.0.0)
hoe-git (1.5.0)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.0, 0.5.0)
id3lib-ruby (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4, 1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
json (1.7.7, 1.7.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.5)
kaminari (0.14.1)
less (2.3.1, 2.2.2)
less-rails (2.3.2, 2.2.6)
libv8 (3.11.8.17 x86_64-linux, 3.11.8.13 x86_64-linux)
lumberg (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
mail (2.4.4, 2.4.3, 2.2.14)
mime-types (1.22, 1.21, 1.17.2, 1.16)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
minitest (4.7.1, 4.6.1)
mongrel (1.1.5)
multi_json (1.7.2, 1.6.1, 1.1.0)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
mysql (2.9.1, 2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.3.0, 2.0.23)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0, 1.0.1)
nokogiri (1.5.9, 1.5.6, 1.5.2)
passenger (3.0.11, 3.0.9, 2.2.15)
polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.1)
puma (1.4.0)
racc (1.4.9)
rack (1.4.5, 1.4.1, 1.2.1, 1.1.0)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.13)
rack-ssl (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.5.7)
rails (3.2.11, 3.2.9, 3.2.2, 3.0.3, 2.3.8)
railties (3.2.12, 3.2.11, 3.2.9, 3.2.2, 3.0.3)
rake (10.0.4, 10.0.3, 0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
rake-compiler (0.8.3)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.12.1, 3.12)
ref (1.0.4, 1.0.2)
rexical (1.0.5)
rmagick (2.13.2)
rspec-core (2.13.1, 2.12.2)
rspec-expectations (2.13.0, 2.12.1)
rspec-mocks (2.13.1, 2.12.2)
rspec-rails (2.13.0, 2.12.2)
rubygems-update (2.0.3, 1.8.18, 1.6.2, 1.4.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.2.7, 3.2.6)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.30.0)
sprockets (2.2.2, 2.1.2)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2, 1.2.5)
therubyracer (0.11.4, 0.8.2)
thor (0.18.1, 0.17.0, 0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.7, 1.3.3)
tissue (1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
treetop (1.4.12, 1.4.10, 1.4.9)
trollop (2.0, 1.16.2)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6, 2.2.5)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.35, 0.3.32, 0.3.23)
uglifier (2.0.1, 1.3.0)
validates_existence (0.8.0)
webrat (0.7.3)
websocket (1.0.7)
xpath (2.0.0, 1.0.0)
yaml_db (0.2.3)
```

Comment: sorry for this kind of question, but is there enough memory at your host site?

Comment: According to them there is no limit.

Comment: Unlimited memory is impossible. Memories are expensive, and are related to CPU capability. Hosting companies can have hype on "unlimited traffic" and "unlimited storage" with lots of hidden limitation, but they would never say "unlimited memory".

Comment: can you try something like `bundle cache`, `bundle lock`, `cd vendor/cache && gem install --local --no-rdoc --no-ri *.gem` in app root on a target machine?

Comment: I suggest you change a hosting. Your app is under `public_html`, that's not acceptable.

Comment: @ted, is that an attempt to lower the memory usage?

Comment: @BillyChan, can you please explain?  That's how the site's demo recommended I set it up.

Comment: @JoeEssey, files under that folder are public accessible as per normal hosting settings. Imagine your yml files including confidential APIs been crawled by search engines! And there are more downsides.

Comment: @BillyChan, I checked out the hosting dir again.  It looks like it copied everything in to a www directory.  Can I just delete everything in public_html after I get it running?

Comment: @JoeEssey, if this is a shared hosting plan, I'm afraid you can't. If it's VPS or dedicated server, you should be able to. In the later case you need to consult their support for details.

Comment: @JoeEssey, yes, exactly. Sorry, missed your message

Comment: @JoeEssey, so, the problem still exists?

Comment: @ted, I spent most of my day converting my app to be rails 1.8.7 compatible.  I got it up on my system so I know it's not a dependencies problem.  I tried the steps you suggested but no luck.  Just updated my support ticket with Site5.